# 2 Left Joins pointing 1 table

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
*
FROM dvcam

LEFT JOIN format AS format1 ON
dvcam.ID_Format=format.ID_Format,

originaltape
LEFT JOIN format AS format2 ON
originaltape.RO_Format=format.ID_Format
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Format contains ID_Format and Format where is saved the name (dvd, vhs, etc)

I need to show the Format(name) from dvcam table and from originaltape

Comment: What's the relationship between originaltape and dvcam?

Comment: How does originaltape join to dvcam?

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess:

```
SELECT
*
FROM dvcam
LEFT JOIN format AS format1 ON
dvcam.ID_Format=format1.ID_Format,

originaltape
LEFT JOIN format AS format2 ON
originaltape.RO_Format=format2.ID_Format
```

Comment: This appears to be identical to the query in the OP.

Comment: No, he messed up the aliases, but there's more wrong than that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `,` after the first join and fix the aliases in the `on` clauses:

```
SELECT *
FROM dvcam left join
     format AS format1
     ON dvcam.ID_Format=format1.ID_Format left join
     originaltape left join
     format AS format2
     ON originaltape.RO_Format=format2.ID_Format
```

Comment: In mysql and php the , is needed.. for example FROM dvcam, actors, comments  WHERE bla bla bla.. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Musikdoktor . . . The comma is a synonym for `cross join` in the `from clause`.  It is only used when you don't use proper join syntax.  This query is using proper join syntax, so the `,` should be causing a syntax error.

Comment: @Musikdoktor, no the comma is not neeeded and using it is a sign of lack of knowledge of database programming priniciples. It is an implicit join and they should never under any circumstances be used as  they are a SQL antipattern. In particular, you should not use them in conjunction with explicit joins like the left joins or you will have trouble as you have found. Since you had no where clause for original tape, it appears you needed a cross join? If not then taht is part of your problem as that is most certainly what you wrote and it is a common proble with using implicit joins.

Comment: Good to know.. Thanks Gord and Hlgem

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain more and which database are you using (Oracle, SQL Server, MYSql...etc)

**EDIT:**
you need to define the relation between dvcam and originaltape, a join like the one you have would not work if dvcam relation to originaltape is not 1-1. On the other hand if it is 1-1 then you can do something like this

```
Select *
from
  (SELECT *
    FROM dvcam inner join 
      format as f1 
     /*assuming every record has a format field */
     on dvcam.id_format =f1.id_format) dv inner join
  (SELECT *
    FROM originaltape inner join 
      format as f2 
     /*assuming every record has a format field */
     on originaltape.id_format =f2.id_format) ot 
  on dv.?? = ot.??
```

HTH
Jafar

Comment: I'm making a query from php over mysql. Thanks for the help

Comment: I am not sure if the post you have indicated as an answer would give you correct data, as HLGEM and Gordon pointed out. Your join is invalid. Double check your data

Answer (score 0):

you can try this, it should works on any database:

```
SELECT
*
FROM dvcam
LEFT JOIN format AS format1 ON
dvcam.ID_Format=format1.ID_Format
LEFT JOIN originaltape ON
originaltape.RO_Format=format1.ID_Format
```

Answer (score -3):

This is what i made.. now it works..

```
SELECT dvcam.*, format.Format AS Format, Format2.Format AS Format2

FROM
dvcam
LEFT JOIN format ON
dvcam.ID_Format=format.ID_Format,

originaltape
LEFT JOIN format AS format2 ON
originaltape.RO_Format=format2.ID_Format
```

Thanks for all your help and time..